# How to add animation to the same element separately in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` and I want to apply animation to it.

#### When Clicked on hamburger icon

When I click on the hamburger menu, it should appear from left to right and it does correctly.
[image]

Here it appears like this, with left to right animation
[image]

### When clicked on left icon

Now When after it appears to the screen, when I click to the leftIcon, it should disappear from right to left.

However, I manage to make the first animation appearing from left to right but I don't know how to add another animation to the same div when the left Icon is pressed.

**Code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaBars, FaArrowLeft } from "react-icons/fa";
import "./Sidebar.css";
function Sidebar() {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);
  const showHideSidebar = () => {
    return setSidebar(!sidebar);
  };
  return (
    <div className="side__bar">
      <div className="top__side__bar">
        <div className="the__icon" onClick={showHideSidebar}>
          <FaBars></FaBars>
        </div>
        <div className="the__bar__title">DASA</div>
      </div>
      {sidebar ? (
        <div>
          <TheSideBar></TheSideBar>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
    </div>
  );
  function TheSideBar() {
    return (
      <div className="the__side__bar">
        <div className="left__side__bar">
          <div className="the__bar__title">DASA</div>
          <div className="the__icon">
            <FaArrowLeft onClick={showHideSidebar}></FaArrowLeft>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sidebar;
```

**css**

```
.the__side__bar {
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(187, 183, 183);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(187, 183, 183);
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  animation: mymove 1s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: -300px;
  }
  to {
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can Add Class with body then you can control sidebar part using css.

```
const openMenu = () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('sidebar-open');
  };
  const closeMenu = () => {
    document.body.classList.toggle('sidebar-open');
  };
```

CSS

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  left: -100%;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.sidebar-open .sidebar {left: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the menu menu items only change the css class.

```js
function toggleMenu() {
  $('.spanPos1').toggleClass('rotA45Top');
  $('.spanPos3').toggleClass('rotA45Bottom');
  $('.sideMenu').toggleClass('showMenu');
  $('.btnMenu').toggleClass('btnMenu_Move');
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #DDD;
  padding: 10px;
}

.sideMenu {
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(187, 183, 183);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(187, 183, 183);
  width: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s;
  top: 0;
  left: -300px;
}

.spanLine {
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.spanPos1 {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.spanPos2 {
  top: 10px;
  left: 0px;
}

.spanPos3 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
}

.btnMenu {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 24px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.rotA45Top {
  margin-top: 3px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 20px;
  left: -5px;
}

.rotA45Bottom {
  margin-top: -3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 20px;
  left: -5px;
}

.showMenu {
  left: 0;
}

.btnMenu_Move {
  z-index: 2;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="btnMenu" onclick="toggleMenu()">
    <span class="spanLine spanPos1"></span>
    <span class="spanLine spanPos2"></span>
    <span class="spanLine spanPos3"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sideMenu"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```